# Time Duration Modelling for Hidden Markov Models

Tags: hidden-markov-model, forward-backward

As we know, one of the major weakness of conventional HMMs is related to the modelling of
state duration, as the probability of state occupancy decreases exponentially with time. There are multiple solutions to that, and one of them centers around replacing the conventional forward (and also backward) recursion step:
\begin{align}
\alpha_t(j) = \sum\limits_i \alpha_{t-1}(i)a_{ij}b_j(O_t)
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
\alpha_t(j) = \sum\limits_{\tau}\sum\limits_{i \neq j}\alpha_{t-\tau}(i)a_{ij}d_j(\tau)\prod\limits_{l=1}^\tau b_j(O_{t-\tau+1})
\end{align}
At time $t$, the process enters state $i$ for duration $\tau$ with probability density $d(\tau)$ during which the observations $O_{t+1}, ..., O_{t+\tau}$ are generated. It then transfers to state $j$ with transition probability $a_{ij}$ only after the appropriate $\tau$ observations have occurred in the state $i$.

Now, the the problem is that in order to obtain $\alpha_t(j)$ we need to know all $\tau$ previous values of $\alpha$. Provided that we only know the initial value i.e. $\alpha_0(j)$ it seems to be impossible to use this formula, as for example $\alpha_5(j)$ would require all previous values provided that $\tau = 4$. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: It’s tricky to write an answer here—are you looking for anything more than “yes, your interpretation is correct”?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy you're right, now as I read my question it seems to be kinda ambiguous. corrected.